# Ruby test coverage tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, code-coverage, deep-cover.rb

I need a tool which measures test coverage under Ruby.

I tried rcov, but couldn't install it under Windows, Cygwin, or Ubuntu.

Which programs (not necessarily free) calculate the branch and/or line coverage of tests in Ruby and work with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[**Simplecov**](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov). Rcov doesn't work so well under Ruby 1.9.*, but simplecov does.

Comment: The link above to Simplecov points to a fork of https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov, which is currently the most up-to-date version of the library.

Comment: You're welcome, @Mori. I like your answer. Simplecov is indeed very nice.

Answer (score 3):

You also have [deep-cover](https://github.com/deep-cover/deep-cover) which aims to be more complete than the mentioned examples.

From the Readme:

> Deep Cover aims to be the best coverage tool for Ruby code:
>
> more accurate line coverage
>
> branch coverage
>
> can be used as a drop-in replacement for the built-in Coverage library.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ruby's built in [Coverage feature](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/coverage/rdoc/Coverage.html) if you are wanting something very simple. It is what Simplecov uses under the hood.