# Ruby Test Coverage Mapping Tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, code-coverage

I want to map a large number of tests (rspec, test-unit, cucumber, selenium, etc.) over a very large (RoR) code base and look for intersections and overlaps in an attempt to reduce the number of tests being run, while maintaining code coverage. I have looked at SimpleCov (per: [Ruby test coverage tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639945/ruby-test-coverage-tool)) and it's not quite extensive enough.

An aside, a colleague mentioned a Hudson plugin that might be what I'm looking for, but couldn't remember it's name and some basic searches didn't yield any useful results.

Thanks!
-j

Comment: Hudson was renamed Jenkins a while ago. Its a continuous integration server. It could *run* your coverage tests for you, but it doesn't _includ_ any.

Comment: Since `simplecov` is so standard, it would be good for you to state your assumptions about what makes it "not extensive"

Comment: My assumptions on it being "not extension *enough*" is that it doesn't do what I'm looking to do, from what I can see. I use SimpleCov in all of my personal work and in the site I'm referring to above and it's a great tool, it just doesn't solve the problem I'm trying to in my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the primary answer is, there isn't really anything out there, at least, not that I could find. However, that said, for most apps and in most cases, SimpleCov is what people are looking for.

Comment: Be sure the check out `DeepCover`

Answer (score 1):

why isn't simplecov enough ?

You can have a look at what simplecov is using below: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/coverage/rdoc/Coverage.html

SimpleCov is just using an api added in ruby 1.9.

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't very familiar with SimpleCov (which we do use) at the time of asking this question. That said, given the initial problem I mentioned, SimpleCov doesn't solve it. At least not from what I've seen. I'm looking for something that I can drop in at top level and it will explicitly identify overlapping tests and identify tests that can be removed without losing coverage. I'll dig in a little deeper to "coverage.so" and see if there's something there I'm missing though. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that when do you decide that two tests overlaps ? two tests can execute the same code without really overlapping, that is hard to isolate everything and not always a good thing to do. I really doubt anything fully automated can really tell you that.

Comment: agreed, starting to think what I'm looking for doesn't exist, because it's not exactly possible. Thanks!